# Wordpress: Creating new custom post from existing metadata of a regular post

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I have the following issue:
I run a blog about books, and each post follows a pattern like this: '5 great books about [subject]'.

Whenever I publish an article (type: 'post'), I also fill in a set of identical custom fields for each book mentioned in the post (ie: name of the book, author, no. of pages).

My question is: Is there a possibility to create 5 more distinct custom posts (type: 'book') filled with data inserted in the custom fields attached to the new regular article when I press the 'Publish' button?

The 5 new 'book' posts should get their names from the custom field 'book_title' and content from the custom field 'book_description'. 
Thanks!

Comment: Yep, you can do that. Look into the action `save_post` and `wp_insert_post` function. You can run the action hook `save_post` and then in the callback function that is in that hook, you can use `wp_insert_post`

Comment: Thank you, I will try that and post an update here.